# WCF and "Persistent Connections"

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, connection, load-balancing

I am trying to get my calls to my WCF Services to use my load balancer (An F5).

The problem is that when I try to set one of the machines in the pool to "Disabled" it will still send requests through that machine.

The documentation for F5 says that when a server is Disabled that "Only persistent or active connections allowed".

**I am wondering if WCF would be using a *persistent connection* (or something similar)** that was bypassing the loadbalancer's efforts to Disable the node on the server.

(The goal is to disable the server, get all the active connections out, then update the code on the server, then re-enable it.)

Does WCF use persistant connections by default?  If so, any way to turn that off?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default connections in WCF (you mean - communication channels) 
It depends from explicit or implicit (via factories) hosting configurations.

The most (true-)'persistent' communication is provided by duplex NetTcpBinding (active connections). Durable services allows the other (business-)dimension of persistence (via HTTP, where connections are not always open, active). WCF sessions, reliable sessions - same story - fake 'persistence'.

So check you WCF's (hosting) configuration.